# Angularjs routes optimize

Tags: angularjs

I have an accordion list in my Ionic application which looks like follows:

[image]

**My routes are as follows:**

```
.state('tab.plan', {
      url: '/plan',
       resolve: {
        authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
          return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
        }],
      },
      views: {
        'tab-plan': {
          templateUrl: '/templates/tab-plan.html', <= view responsible for this list
          controller: 'planCtrl'
        }
      },
      cache: false
    })

  .state('tab.exerciseTest', {
      url: '/plan/2',          <= hardcoding exerciseId as a trial, must be optimized 
       resolve: {
        authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
          return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
        }],
      },
      views: {
        'tab-plan': {
          templateUrl: '/templates/template1.html',
          controller: 'template1Ctrl'
        }
      },
       cache: false
    })

    .state('tab.exercise', {
      url: '/plan/:exerciseId', 
       resolve: {
        authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
          return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
        }],
      },
      views: {
        'tab-plan': {
          templateUrl: '/templates/video.html', <= For physical exercises
          controller: 'videoCtrl'
        }
      },
       cache: false
    })
```

This list has total 12 elements (i.e. exercises) and when I click on any element it opens up the exercise page.

However, these elements are of two types: exercise 1 (i.e.Best Stretch), 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12 are physical exercises and they have single HTML and a common logic (i.e. video.html, videoCtrl) and based on the exerciseId passed as a `stateParam` from the list to videoCtrl (i.e. 1,3,5,7,9,11,12), corresponding model values will be populated for different exercises.

excerpt from the template of the accordion list:

```
<a class="item item-icon-left item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(day)" ng-repeat="exercise in day.exercises" type="item-text-wrap"
   href="#/tab/plan/{{exercise.id}}">
  {{exercise.name}}        
</a>
```

However, all other exercises (i.e. 2, 4, 6, 8, 10) are all memory games and they all have different logic and hence different HTMLs.

Right now for example When I click on **Simon game** I handle the navigation to load a page as:

```
.state('tab.exerciseTest', {
          url: '/plan/2', //:dayId/:exerciseId
           resolve: {
            authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
              return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
            }],
          },
          views: {
            'tab-plan': {
              templateUrl: '/templates/template1.html',
              controller: 'template1Ctrl'
            }
          },
           cache: false
        })
```

Here I am hardcoding the exerciseId value to 2 and then binding it to specific template and controller. This works, but the problem I will have is to manually do the same for all remaining memory games and it doesn't seem to be optimal.

**How and where can I build a logic which will decide based on the exerciseId, which template and controller to use? Is it possible to implement something like this in routes?**

Comment: you can leave the url as a template (e.g., '/:dayId/:exerciseId'), and use the $state provider in your controller to go to the desired state with the first argument and any parameters as the second: $state.go('tab.exerciseText'. {dayId: 'plan'. exerciseId: '2'};

Comment: Okay! I will try so